# value error(line 7 for name, home) when using csv library in python CS50P file i/o

Tags: python, file-io, valueerror

```
import csv

students = []

with open("stu1.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for name, home in reader:
        students.append({"name": name}, {"home": home})

for student in sorted(students, key =lambda student:student["name"]):
    print(f"{student['name']} is from {student['home']}")
```

stu1.csv  contains below data

```
Harry, Number, Pivet Drive
Ron, The burrow
Draco, Malfoy manor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. There were actually 2 errors.

1. there were 3 columns (in the first row) and you are unpacking 2 values.
2. the `append()` takes 1 dict, but you were passing 2 dicts.

with the error fixed, this works:

```
import csv

students = []

f = "C:\\test\\test_file.csv"
with open(f) as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for name, home in reader:
        students.append({"name": name, "home": home})


for student in sorted(students, key =lambda student:student["name"]):
    print(f"{student['name']} is from {student['home']}")
```

returns this:

```
Draco is from  Malfoy manor
Harry is from  Number
Ron is from  The burrow
```

Answer (score 0):

For the context, I believe this comes from CS50 lecture (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLRL_NcnK-4&t=28335s&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org) at 8:00:00 - 8:12:09.

In his example, David Malan has his input file as:

```
Harry,"Number Four, Privet Drive"
Ron, The burrow
Draco, Malfoy manor
```

Notice in the first line text after `,` spans inside `""` which makes `csv.reader()` recognise it as one single element and does not raise the `ValueError: too many values to unpack`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34812729)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Koedlt. I still do not understand why my answer does not provide the answer to the question asked by OP.  Clearly, OP is missing the appropriate quotes ("") in the input which is raising the ValueError.